# Github permission denied when cloning in Vagrant

Tags: github, ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys

Im using an [ubuntu](https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/ubuntu2010) vagrant box for my dev environment.

I've ran the `ssh-keygen` command and generated a `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file and copy and pasted it into my github settings for ssh key.

However whenever I run git clone to a private repository that my account has access to, it gave the error

```
vagrant@ubuntu2010:/vagrant_data$ git clone git@github.com:aellym0/cs4215_dependent_types.git
Cloning into 'cs4215_dependent_types'...
/vagrant_data/cs4215_dependent_types/.git: Permission denied
```

I tried to work around this by cloning in my local (not vagrant) into a shared directory with vagrant, but when i am working on vscode connected to vagrant I am unable to write the files in the repo with an EACCESS error.

Here is my vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu2010"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./data", "/vagrant_data"
end
```

Here is the vagrant ssh config

```
Host CS4215
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/haliq/Documents/sch/Y5S2/CS4215/vagrantbox/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, test if your key is working with:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

If you see a Welcome message ('`Hi xxx,...`'), you can then check if the error you have means something else. Specifically, a write error because of some `Error::EACCES` issue, which would have nothing to do with SSH.
For example, some [vendoring issue which should not include `.git`](https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/237#issuecomment-72906999)

Comment: im getting 
`
Hi <my username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
`
with a debug1: Exit status 1

Comment: @iluvAS Exactly: that means the issue is not with SSH, but with some kind of write access on your Vagrant environment. You can therefore put Git aside, and focus on "how can I check write access is working?"

Comment: it might be due to shared folder on root, im currently not using the shared folder and doing everything on /home/vagrant seems to be working. thanks